# With declarative SQLAlchemy class, how can I check which columns are indexed for any given model?

Tags: python, database, indexing, sqlalchemy

I'm developing a generic interface that will allow other devs to define (with a list of just field names) which fields they want the end user to be able to sort and filter.

Now, sorting and filtering works best when there's an index on the database column, but I would like to warn the developer that they are allowing filtering/sorting on a column that does not have a index, which may hurt performance, and then suggest they should add an `index` parameter to the column definition or create an `Index()` instance on that column.

But inspecting the model, I can only see if `Column.index` is `True`, but I can't tell if the column has an index when using the `Index()` constructor.

Note that I can't access the actual database, I have to work with the declarative stuff only.

Thanks!